# Why std::declval cannot be directly replaced by std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval, the possible implementation of `declval` is following:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool always_false = false;
 
template<typename T>
typename std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type declval() noexcept
{
    static_assert(always_false<T>, "declval not allowed in an evaluated context");
}
```

I am trying to replace the use case of `std::declval<T>()` with `std::add_rvalue_reference<Test>::type` but it doesn't compile. Why is that?

Following is my testing code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct Test {
    int func() {
        return 1;
    }
};

template<typename T>
constexpr bool always_false = false;
 
template<typename T>
typename std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type Decltype() noexcept
{
    static_assert(always_false<T>, "declval not allowed in an evaluated context");
}

int main() {
    if (std::is_same_v<decltype(std::add_rvalue_reference<Test>::type.func()),int>) {
        std::cout <<"same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout <<"different\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Always post error along with your question, always.

Comment: The important part is the "val" in `declval()`. It is a function that returns a value. The `::type` is just a type, not a value of that type.

Comment: “I am trying to replace the use case of `std::declval<T>()` with `std::add_rvalue_reference<Test>::type`” — what for? What is wrong with `std::declval`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an instance of `type` to check what the non-`static` member function `func` returns:

```cpp
if (std::is_same_v<decltype(std::add_rvalue_reference<Test>::type{}.func()),int>)
//                                                               ^^
```

or

```cpp
if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(std::add_rvalue_reference_t<Test>{}.func()),int>)
//                                                                     ^^
```

This will however not work unless `type` is default constructible and destructible. You could use your own `Decltype` function template to fix that:

```cpp
std::is_same_v<decltype(Decltype<Test>().func()),int>
```

or, start with a `Test*` instead:

```cpp
std::is_same_v<decltype(static_cast<Test*>(nullptr)->func()),int>

// or if you really want an rvalue reference:

std::is_same_v<decltype(static_cast<Test&&>(*static_cast<Test*>(nullptr)).func()),int>
// or
std::is_same_v<decltype(std::move(*static_cast<Test*>(nullptr)).func()),int>
```

Sidenote: `Decltype` is a misleading name. `Declval` would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that `decltype(std::add_rvalue_reference<Test>::type` is a **type**, and you're trying to call a function on that type, which is not allowed.

The **member access** `operator.` takes a class object as its left operand, which is not the case in your example.

---

To **solve** this, you can create an object of the resulting type and then use that object to call the member function.

```
//--------------------------------------------VV---------->create an object of the resulting type and then call the member function on that object
decltype(std::add_rvalue_reference<Test>::type{}.func())
```

Answer (score 0):

`decltype(unevaluded_expresssion)` is supposed to give the compile-time type of its operand - without calculating(evaluating) the operand. Hence the `unevaluded_expresssion` is supposed to be an expression resulting a value(in contrast to a type), but it is not actually evaluated as a result of using `decltype`.

Now, how can we tell the compiler that the expression is supposed to have a sub-expression consisting of a **hypothetical, unspecified/general value** of a **specific type**?

Assume asking the compiler to "find **result type** of **adding** an istance of **type `C`** to an istance of **type `B`**, and name it as **`my_type`**. Assume that we are going to include addition after implicit conversation to proper types.

How do you compose it?
First attempt:

```
//Will this compile?!
using my_type = decltype (B{}+C{});
```

The problem with above is that it requires both `B` and `C` to be default constructible. What if either or both of them lack a default constructor?

If the properties of both types are known, you can try to find valid expressions to produce values of the two types. What if the types `B` and `C` appear as dependent/argument types in a template definition? You no more know how to compose an expression that results in values of proper types?!

The better attempt would be:

```
using my_type = decltype (std::declval<B>() + std::declval<C>());
```

`std::declval<X>()` just means a **fictitious value** of **type X**. There is no way you can express this without something like `std::declval`. The `requires` clause is the only exception, but it is another very long story.